# Hide other children in mobile nav

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys i am trying to pull this off but having some issues getting to the right siblings. My intentions are to have a side sliding navigation that has around 4 levels total. I would like the previous list items hidden so that the opened one is not over the top of the other one but slides back when back is clicked. Some way to add a class hidden then remove it when necessary. Here is what i have so far.

HTML

```js
// Mobile navigation


function mobileMenuInit(state) {
  // Toggling the hamburger nav class
 $('.mobile-menu').toggleClass('active');
 // Adding Class to the body to slide the menu in.
 $('body').toggleClass('menu-active');
  // Removing any active classes from the children menu triggers to 'reset" the menu
 $('.mobile-menu-trigger--sub').removeClass('active');
}

function mobileMenuChildInit(state) {
    // adding the active class when clicked.
    state.addClass('active');
    // adds a class to anything that wasn't toggled active:
    // todo: remove hidden classes when clicking back + toggling hamburger nav
    state.closest('ul').find('li a').not('.active').addClass('hidden');
}

function mobileMenuBack(state) {
    // finding the closest ul
    var closestActive = state.closest('ul').siblings();
    // removing the active class to go back to the previous menu
    closestActive.removeClass('active');
}


// Firing functions when appropriate items are clicked.
$('#nav-icon').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    mobileMenuInit();
});

$('.mobile-menu-trigger--sub').click(function(e){
    var clickedElement = $(this);
    mobileMenuChildInit(clickedElement);
});

$('.mobile-menu--back').click(function(e){
    var clickedElement = $(this);
    mobileMenuBack(clickedElement);
});
// End Mobile Navigation
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
$white:            #ffffff;

/// Anything that goes behind the main pane
/// @type behind
$z-level-back: 0;


/// Wrapper Level
/// @type main
$z-level-mid: 10;

/// Everything on top of Wrapper
/// @type front
$z-level-fore: 100;
/// @type Size
$margin-vertical:              30px;

/// @type Size
$margin-vertical--small:       15px;

$margin-vertical--supersmall: 7px;

/// @type Size
$margin-vertical--large:       45px;

/// @type Size
$margin-horizontal:            2.5%;

/// @type Size
$margin-horizontal--small:    1%;

/// @type Size
$margin-horizontal--large:     5%;

$default-animation: .35s all;

/// @type String
$font-size:        20px;

/// @type String
$font-size--small: 14px;

/// @type String
$font-size--large: 30px;

.mobile-nav li {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: $margin-horizontal;
}
.mobile-nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mobile-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: $font-size;
  z-index: $z-level-fore;
  left: -100%;
  transition: $default-animation;
  height: calc(100vh);
  overflow: scroll;
  top: 97px;
}

.mobile-menu.active {
  left: 0;
}

.mobile-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mobile-menu li {
  background-color: $primary-blue;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

.mobile-menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: $white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mobile-menu--back, .mobile-menu a:hover {
  color: $white;
  background-color: $secondary-blue;
}

.mobile-menu a .fa {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.mobile-menu a .fa:first-of-type {
}

.mobile-menu a .fa:last-of-type {
}

/* Animation Bits */
.mobile-menu {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.mobile-menu [class*="mobile-menu--"] ~ ul, .mobile-menu [class*="mobile-menu--"] ~ ul > ul {
  top: 0;
  left: -200%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: $default-animation;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  height: calc(100vh);
}
.mobile-menu.subnav-active > ul > li {
  background-color: black;
}
.mobile-menu.subnav-active > ul > li > a {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.mobile-menu .active ~ ul > li > a {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mobile-menu .active ~ ul {
  left: 0%;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-chevron-right {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-trigger--sub .mobile-chevron-right {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-chevron-left {
  display: inline;
  margin-right:15px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="hidden-md hidden-lg mobile-menu">
          <ul>
            <!-- Level 1 Item 1 -->
            <li class="main-item"><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-one mobile-menu-trigger--sub">Our Plans<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
              <ul>
                <!-- Level 2 Sub Items for 1 -->
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--back"> <span class="mobile-chevron-left fa fa-chevron-left"></span>Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two">Our Plans - Home<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two mobile-menu-trigger--sub">Individual &#38; Family<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
                  <ul>
                    <!-- Level 2 Sub Items for 1 -->
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--back"> <span class="mobile-chevron-left fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Back</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Individual &#38; Family<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Level Three<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Level Three<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- Level 2 Sub Items for 1 -->
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two mobile-menu-trigger--sub">Employer Group<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
                  <!-- Group Level 2 Sub Items for 1 -->
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--back"> <span class="mobile-chevron-left fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Back</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Employer Group - Home<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three mobile-menu-trigger--sub">Large Group Plans<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--back"> <span class="mobile-chevron-left fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Back</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-four">Large Group Plans - Home<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-four">Level Four<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-four">Level Four<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three mobile-menu-trigger--sub">Small Group Plans<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--back"> <span class="mobile-chevron-left fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Back</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-four">Small Group Plans - Home<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-four">Level Four<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-four">Level Four<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Why RMHP<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Health Care Reform<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Find a Broker<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Document Library<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">How to Enroll<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Get a Quote<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <!-- Level 1 Sub Items for 2 -->
                  <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two mobile-menu-trigger--sub">Medicare<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--back"> <span class="mobile-chevron-left fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Back</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Medicare - Home<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Medicare 2<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Medicare 3<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two mobile-menu-trigger--sub">Medicad / CHP+<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--back"> <span class="mobile-chevron-left fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Back</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Medicad / CHP+ - Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Medicad 2<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Medicad 3<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="main-item"><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-one">Find a Provider</a></li>
            <li class="main-item"><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-one mobile-menu-trigger--sub">About RMHP<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--back"> <span class="mobile-chevron-left fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">About RMHP - Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two mobile-menu-trigger--sub">Level Two<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--back"> <span class="mobile-chevron-left fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Back</a><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Level Three<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Level Three<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Level Three<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two mobile-menu-trigger--sub">Level Two<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--back"> <span class="mobile-chevron-left fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Back</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Level Three<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Level Three<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-three">Level Three<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two">Level Two<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two">Level Two<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="main-item"><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-one mobile-menu-trigger--sub">Learning Center<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--back"> <span class="mobile-chevron-left fa fa-chevron-left"> </span>Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two">Learning Center - Home<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two">Level Two<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two">Level Two<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-two">Level Two<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-one">Contact Us<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
            <li> <a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-one">Iam a Provider<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
            <li> <a href="#" class="mobile-menu--level-one">I am a Broker<span class="mobile-chevron-right fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: can you please add a fiddle or a working example?

Comment: Not sure why this is not working i have it working locally. The issue is it is going to the first ul > li > a not the li out side of the open one. Not sure im even explaining this right.

https://jsfiddle.net/Thrilom/5pz4ysk4/